# Configuring APC with Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, centos, apc, opcode-cache

I am working on a website which is hosted on a VPS with CENTOS 5.4 i686 virtuozzo installed. I have a drupal installation on the server which gets around 100s of authenticated users at the same time.But at a certain point of time the server stopped responding and the site went offline. So, I tried installing the opcode cache - Alternative PHP Cache.

While the rest parts of the server work fine, the Drupal installation crashes as soon as I install PECL APC with the following message
Fatal error:Cannot run code from this file in conjunction with non encoded files in /home/apogee/public_html/2010/themes/zen/zen/block.tpl.php.

Could you please tell me a way to properly configure Drupal to use APC ?
Thanks
niting

Answer (score 3):

I think the error comes from Zend Encoder...if you don't need it installed then uninstall it and see if that fixes things. If you do need it (closed-source module?), then not sure if that and APC can play nicely together...

Answer (score 2):

you must be disable APC on php.ini

apc.enabled=0

APC and Zend Optimizer can't work with together

Answer (score 0):

David Strauss at four kitchens has done some work on getting Pressflow (Performance tuned Drupal distribution) to work well with APC https://wiki.fourkitchens.com/display/PF/Tuning+APC.

With that much concurrent usage it may be worth your while to look into pressflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of websites using APC and I've never seen that kind of error -- even with the Drupal-based ones.

After a bit of searching, it seems related to Zend Optimizer and/or Encoder (see the last answer on [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/381622), for instance), and not to Drupal itself.

I suppose you should use either Zend products, or APC, but not a combinaison of both.